# Ethernet Network Disconnecting - Atheros AR8152

Tags: wireless, internet

I'm new to Ubuntu and i just brows the web and edit photo's.
I'm running a Ubuntu server for 1 year now and i love it.
But now when I'm just doing something the WiFi icon look like it searching and then it connects but without a notification. but instead i get a disconnected error.
here is a screen shot:

[image]
Here is some of the output of `lspci -v`:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8468
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
        Memory at f7fc0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
        I/O ports at ec00 [size=128]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: atl1c

02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
        Subsystem: AzureWave AW-NE785 / AW-NE785H 802.11bgn Wireless Full or Half-size Mini PCIe Card
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
        Memory at fbff0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Comment: +1 for using Gimp ;-) . What hardware is your ethernet device using, with what `driver`? You can use `lspci -v` or `lshw -C network`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Lw8Qpb2L And i'm a Gimp lover :P but i need to change the splash :D

Comment: Errr... You have TWO network cards shown, do you know which one has the problem, or whether the other one works? I *think* the AR8152 has the right driver... But it varys :-s

Comment: uhmm well it's just a laptop so i don't know but i think it has only 1 network car and i think i use AR9285 for wifi and the other for lan so i think it's the first one

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? And does it work with other wired networks?

Comment: 13.10 and i got internet connection all the time i'll try it now with a cable

Comment: According to the image that you've shared, its says **Ethernet network** which indicates to a LAN but not wireless. That's pretty strange.. And the output you've shared, 2nd one is your wireless adapter. Have you tried disabling restarting your network-manager itself. If not, try `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: I did try it but i still get that error every 5 mins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did fix it!
i did go to the connection icon and then to settings and deleted the ethernet connection!
so now it doesn't give me the error!

Comment: Strange, seems like a bug that should be filed

Comment: Well done! :D Bit weird though...

Comment: Yes i know should i write a mail to them?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your kernel is up to date and try:

```
sudo -s
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Comment: It didn't work :( But thank you for helping Btw it works with a wired connection

Comment: @virtualxtc What does this have to do with ethernet?

Comment: @chili555 the user claims to be using wifi when this happens.

Comment: @virtualxtc Indeed i'm using WIfi when this happens. Btw my laptop is dual-booted with windows so if you want to I can give you the good Network driver ;)